# Différence entre un sport et un travail ?

Tags: vocabulaire, sport

La différence entre un sport et un travail me semble universellement et **intuitivement** admise.

En revanche en réfléchissant un peu plus loin à leurs définitions je trouve cette différence assez problématique.

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sport) donne comme définition :

> Quelqu’une des sortes d’exercices physiques, de jeux d’adresse ou de force. Le sport est un ensemble d'exercices, le plus souvent physiques, se pratiquant sous forme de jeux individuels ou collectifs pouvant donner lieu à des compétitions.

Le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sport/74327?q=sport#73493) :

> Activité physique visant à améliorer sa condition physique.
>   Ensemble des exercices physiques se présentant sous forme de jeux individuels ou collectifs, donnant généralement lieu à compétition, pratiqués en observant certaines règles précises.

- Le premier terme qui revient est celui d'**activité physique**. De nombreux jobs font l'objet d'activités physiques régulières comme les sapeurs pompiers, le BTP, ...
- Pour les autres sports qui correspondent plutôt à des jeux d'**adresse** ou de **réflexion** (tir à l'arc, échecs, ...) on trouve des équivalents dans le monde du travail. Le monde de l'artisanat demande une certaine adresse, et la réflexion est une composante essentielle dans la recherche.
- Est-ce que alors ce pourrait être le terme **jeu** qui ferait la différence ? Je ne pense pas, on m'a récemment fait participer à un jeu de rôle dans le cadre d'entretiens d'embauche, et les jeux de pouvoir sont omniprésents dans les hautes sphères des entreprises, voire de la politique.
- Les sports d'équipe/individuels ont également leurs pendants dans le monde du travail. Et inutile de parler de l'aspect **compétitif** du sport qui est également fortement représenté dans le cadre professionnel.
- Le Larousse ajoutait l'aspect d'**amélioration** de sa condition physique. Mais le fait que votre travail vous nourrisse, vous paye vos soins, etc... ne le fait pas également participer à votre condition physique ?
- Alors peut-être qu'un travail vous **fait vivre** alors qu'un sport non ? Pourtant de nombreuses personnes vivent de la pratique du sport.
- Le Larousse insiste également sur le fait que le sport possède un certain nombre de **règles** précises, mais le monde travail possède également ses règles, et même ses arbitres.
- Est-ce que le **plaisir** ne ferait-il pas alors la distinction entre sport et travail ? Là encore je ne pense pas, de nombreuses personnes j'espère pratiquent encore leur travail par passion, et de nombreux jobs (le développement informatique par exemple) sont pratiqués par d'autres personnes dans le cadre de leurs loisirs.

Suite à cette réflexion j'aurais tendance à dire que **tout travail pourrait être considéré comme un sport**. L'inverse moins.

**Est-ce que vous auriez des éléments auxquels je n'ai pas pensé qui permettraient de distinguer un travail qui ne soit pas un sport ?**

Comment: Est-ce que cette question concerne vraiment la langue française? Il me semble que c'est une question de philosophie, posée en français.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a reflection that can be achieved in any language and is not directly related to french.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt la question de fond, et qui a bien été comprise vu les deux réponses ci-dessous, reste d'approfondir la définition des mots *sport* et *travail*. La définition des dictionnaires me laissant sur ma faim. Et à mon humble opinion c'est le genre de question qui a sa place sur ce site.

Comment: Selon la définition du Larousse, la distinction me semble claire: L'objectif du travail n'est pas d'améliorer sa condition physique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un travail est (le plus souvent) rémunéré et contraignant (étymologiquement, travail vient d'un instrument de torture, tripalium). C'est une activité productive.

Un sport n'est pas normalement rémunéré et c'est un loisir choisi. sport vient de desport, divertissement du corps et de l'esprit. C'est une activité improductive (économiquement parlant).

Dans le cas des sportifs professionnels, il s'agit bien aussi d'un travail puisque les joueurs sont liés par contrat, ne s'amusent pas forcément mais sont productifs en raison des spectateurs payants, produits dérivés, vente de droits , etc.

Un travail n'est le plus souvent pas un sport même accompagné d'exercices physiques ou mentaux.

Comment: En effet l'aspect productif du travail m'avait échappé, très bonne suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

- Pour le sport, il faut des compétences physiologiques et du travail pour réaliser un performance.
- Pour l'art et les métiers créatifs le talent (même s'il ne s'agit que de 5% des efforts mis en œuvre ) et le travail sont la base de la réalisation
- L'artisanat peut déboucher sur l'art lorsque l’œuvre est 'totale' (répond aux règles de l'art avec une innovation ou un 'signature' particulière
- Pour l'exploitation des ressources (agriculture, industries, services ...), il y a dans le travail une répétition industrielle, une *besogne*, une soumission à une hiérarchie, des objectifs de production d'objets virtuels ou non : la personne qui travaille ne s'améliore pas (même si elle doit avoir été formée pour le poste occupé) mais fournit un effort physique ou intellectuelle pour produire une richesse dont elle ne récolte que son salaire et peut-être un avancement, à l'encontre du sportif, de l'artisan ou de l'artiste qui récolte le fruit de leur travail en affinant leur maîtrise et leur 'soi'.

Naturellement dans la vie courante, certaines personnes s'épanouissent dans leur travail, mais cela n'en fait ni des sportifs, ni des artistes.